# Getting Problem when try to connect mySAP WCF using .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#

i'm trying to connect a MySAP SOAP service using WCF Client generator VS 2019, but unluckily i got an error

> System.Exception: 'The HTTP request is unauthorized with client
>   authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received
>   from the server was 'Basic realm="SAP NetWeaver Application Server
>   [PXP/100]"'.'

Here my sample code, for ur information, i use .net core 3.1 and i dont implement any configuration file for this WCF client.

```
List<SAPReadTableService.dt_ReadTableMC_RequestFIELDS> listRequestFIELDSDetailT001W = new List<SAPReadTableService.dt_ReadTableMC_RequestFIELDS>();
                #region fields
                listRequestFIELDSDetailT001W.Add(new SAPReadTableService.dt_ReadTableMC_RequestFIELDS() { FIELDNAME = "NAME1" });
                requestDetailT001W.FIELDS = listRequestFIELDSDetailT001W.ToArray();
                #endregion

                try
                {
                    SAPReadTableService.mi_osReadTableMCClient clientDetailShipmentT001W = new SAPReadTableService.mi_osReadTableMCClient();
                    #region credential
                    clientDetailShipmentT001W.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxx";;
                    clientDetailShipmentT001W.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxx";
                    #endregion

                    SAPReadTableService.dt_ReadTableMC_Response responseDetailShipmentT001W = clientDetailShipmentT001W.mi_osReadTableMC(requestDetailT001W);
                    SAPReadTableService.dt_ReadTableMC_ResponseDATA[] dataDetailShipmentT001W = responseDetailShipmentT001W.DATA;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some security configuration in the Reference.cs, in the GetBindingForEndpoint
something like this

```
result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
            result.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
```

hope this help everyone out-there.. 
cheers thanks